# Removing MySearchDial malware

Tags: malware, virus

My brother decided to install uTorrent on my iMac. In doing so, he accepted the installation of MySearchDial, a browser hijacker. I now have no idea how to remove it. Adding a new tab in Chrome will link to the MySearchDial search engine. I'm not sure how else it's affecting the computer, but it seems slower. The only instructions for removal I've found are for Windows.

Comment: try following search command in Terminal "mdfind mysearchdial" and see what come up with. From there you can delete all of them. In the browser also delete any add ons.

Comment: Instructions for removing from osx are here also: https://storify.com/Computertech/remove-mysearchdial-from-windows-and-mac-os-x-glob-1

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments by [@Scott Porter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/131236/scott-porter), [Spotify](https://storify.com/Computertech/remove-mysearchdial-from-windows-and-mac-os-x-glob-1) has an article that explains how to remove MySearchDial from the OS X.  For the sake of others who may encounter the same issue here is the solution as explained in the article.

> Google Chrome
>
> - Click spanner icon > "Tools" > remove mysearchdial in ‘Extensions’.
>
> Mac OS X
>
> - Apple icon  > **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > choose
>     affected user account > tick mysearchdial > hit minus icon.